# printing data on gui from database python

Tags: python, sqlite, wxpython

I am very new to python and I have created a database in sqlite that records the time when files are copied from one folder to another. I am trying to have my GUI say "Files last transferred on: ____" and to fill the blank with the last date recorded. I am able to print the last record with this code:

```
def lastInsert():
   sql_str = "SELECT DATETIMES from TRANSFER_TIMES ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;"
   cursor = conn.execute(sql_str)
   lastrow = cursor.fetchall()
   print lastrow
```

which prints:

```
[(u'2016-03-09 17:53:02.537000',)]
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get that time stamp to fill in the blank on my GUI. I am using wxpython. It would also be great if i could get it out of unicode.

okay so it now i have

```
def lastInsert():
sql_str = "SELECT DATETIMES from TRANSFER_TIMES ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;"
cursor = conn.execute(sql_str)
lastrow = cursor.fetchall()
lr= lastrow[0][0]
print lr
```

which prints:

```
2016-03-09 17:53:02.537000
```

in my GUI (which is in a different file) I have:

```
wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Files Last Transferred on: " , pos=(10, 130))
```

I want to be able to put that date after "Files Last Transferred on:" so that it changes whenever the last record changes.

Comment: try `print lastrow[0][0]`. If you want us to help you with your GUI, you're going to need to show us code from it.

Comment: Thank you, after putting that in its now prints '2016-03-09 17:53:02.537000'

Comment: You need to assign the `StaticText` to an variable, then you can say `st.SetLabel('new_text')`. If this is going to increase the length, don't forget to `Layout()` the sizer too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of how to do it, with a variable defined as `StaticText`

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_date = "2016-03-09 17:53:02.537000"
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'StaticText Example', size=(400, 100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Files Last Transferred on: " , pos=(10, 130))
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Set Date", pos=(50, 20))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, self.button)
        MySizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        MySizer.Add(self.text, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        MySizer.Add(self.button, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        panel.SetSizer(MySizer)
    def OnClick(self, event):
        self.text.SetLabel("Files Last Transferred on: "+self.my_date)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```